# Spring mvc form:select path is custom map in model attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, hashmap

How to bind a map property of the model and send the selected value back to the controller?

i am able to populate the drop down but on submitting the form getting error 400 - bad request.

MyModel.java:

```
public class MyModel{
    private Map<MySubModel, String> subModel = new HashMap<MySubModel, String>();
    private SubModel subModelSearched;
}
```

SubModel.java:

```
public class SubModel{
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="/mySearch" modelAttribute="myModel" method="post">
    <form:select path="subModelSearched">
        <form:options items="${myModel.subModel}/>
    </form:select>
.....
</form:form>
```

Comment: Change path="myModel" to commandName="myModel" and then submit the form..

Comment: sorry it was a typo.. changed in my question.